# fail to install jupyter on mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter

How can I solve this problem?

`$ pip3 install jupyter`

> Collecting jupyter
>       Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a 
>       problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: 
>       TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - 
>       skipping
>       Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jupyter (from 
>       versions: )
>       No matching distribution found for jupyter

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update pip3?

`pip3 install --upgrade pip`

Or you can try to upgrade pip and download jupyter through it:

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3`

Comment: pip3 install --upgrade pip
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:719) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: try it with sudo ->>>>
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python

Comment: cheers! sudo made everything is alright!! thank you~

Answer (score 0):

1) Upgrade pip by using  curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py for  python3 (https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5236)

2) Workaround: Try to install anaconda version of python from  https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos, jupyter notebook will be installed automatically.

Comment: i solved with lower answer. thank you!